# How to serialize message from Spring cloud SQS listener to listen messages from SNS as well as SQS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am using spring-boot-2.3.6. In my app I have an SQS consumer which is subscribed to SNS, It can also receive messages directly from an SQS producer. So my consumer should be able to serialize messages from both SNS & SQS.

Since it receives messages from both SNS & SQS, I am not sure using both @Payload(Serialize message to Java object if the message is from SQS) & @NotificationMessage(Serialize message to Java object if the message is from SNS) can serialize the object, or is there any other way to serialize the object.

Example code for your reference,

```
Method - 1
-----------
@SqsListener(
            value = QUEUE_NAME_PROPERTY,
            deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS
    )
    public void accountConsumer(
            @Headers Map<String, Object> headers,
            @Payload @NotificationMessage Account payload
    ) {
            // Dispatch message to the handler.

    }
```

or

```
Method - 2
----------
    @SqsListener(
            value = QUEUE_NAME_PROPERTY,
            deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS
    )
    public void accountConsumer(
            @Headers Map<String, Object> headers,
            @Payload Account payload,
            @NotificationMessage Account payload
    ) {
            // Dispatch message to the handler.

    }
```

or

```
Method - 3
----------
    @SqsListener(
            value = QUEUE_NAME_PROPERTY,
            deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS
    )
    public void accountConsumer(String message) {
// Parse header from message
// Get body from message and use objectMapper to convert the string message into Java Object
            // Dispatch message to the handler.

    }
```

Which one we can use to consume messages from SNS & SQS. Or is there any other standard way to consume messages from both? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Curious if you ever found a solution to this, having a single annotation handler method that can accept both SNS and SQS direct messages?

Comment: Hi @E-Riz so for no. I consume string message and then serializing on my own.